# Why jQuery append,text and html function is not working on IE?

Tags: jquery, html, text, append, appendto

I tried .html() .appendTo() and .text() but none of them are working.

This is html.

```
    <div>
       <ul id="list-container>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

This is jQuery.

```
   var url = "http://mobiilivantaa.fi/api/place"; // Change path of JSON HERE !!!
var htmlString = '';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.places, function(i,place){
        //console.log(place.id);
        var placeID = place.id;
        var placeTitle = place.title;
        var placeWWW = 'Siirry internetsivulle';
        var placeHREF = place.www;
        var placeTargetBlank = 'target="_blank"';

htmlString += '<li><a href="#" class="ListTitle" title="'+place.latitude+','+place.longitude+','+place.id+'">'+placeTitle+'</a><a class="ListWWW" href="'+placeHREF+'"'+placeTargetBlank+'>'+placeWWW+'</a></li>';

    });
    //console.log(htmlString);
    $('#list-container').append(htmlString);
});
```

list-container is simple ul tag.

Comment: have you got any error in the js console? `html()` should work as expected

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan No error.

Comment: Try to print the string htmlString to see if something wrong or a var null from JSON

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I tried. htmlString is okay. Working all browser except IE (all ver.)

Comment: Is $('#list-container') an object in IE? May you have that ID tag multiple times accidentally?

Comment: @Zim84 It's not an object for sure. I have this tag only one. :)

Comment: If there is only one element with ID list-container, try to separate the element with a blank space like href="'+placeHREF+'" '+placeTargetBlank+'

Comment: Shouldn't $('#list-container') be an object? since its a jQuery thing...

Comment: try to make your htmlString a jQuery object before .append(jQuery(htmlString)); for example

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I just tried. Not working again.

Comment: @Zim84 Oh yes. I forgot. I'm new.

Comment: @regilero I just tried. Not working.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your $('#list-container'). Can you post your code to a jsFiddle?

Comment: Damn, I don't know why I can't save the fiddle. Even it has no code inside. I will add code above then.

Comment: Here you go @Zim84. I add the html and change to path of json so you can have a look at real data

Comment: What version of I. Also, please google about XSS exploits, as your code appears to be full of them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Just add this on top of the script.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```